# How to convert to object from a string generated by @ToString lombok annotation?

Tags: java, object, tostring, lombok

I have an interesting problem to solve.

Let's consider the following classes (*Person* and *Telephone*):

**Person**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Telephone telephone;
}
```

**Telephone**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Telephone {
    private int codeArea;
    private String number;
}
```

And suppose that I have a *Person* object string generated by the lombok annotation *@ToString*:

```
Person(name=John, age=30, telephone=Telephone(codeArea=16, number=1111-2222))
```

How can I convert the string above to the object again? Is there any library that can help me with this process, or do I have to create manually a parser for it?

I know that there are other ways like generating json or serializing as a java object and then converting it back. However, this is not a solution for me now, as I must have to work with the string mentioned above.

Comment: *How can I convert the string above to the object again?* this is really bad idea

Comment: *I know that there are other ways like generating json or serializing as a java object and then converting it back. However, this is not a solution for me now, as I must have to work with the string mentioned above* this is the right path :D

Comment: You "parse" it yourself, because there's no generic way to do it. You'll eventually be sad about wanting to do this.

Comment: If you want a generic solution - in my opinion, convert those Strings to JSON and use some library like Jackson. If only for Person then just parse it yourself. Both are very bad idea tho.

Comment: @Henrique Buzachero: Why do we want to do this in that way? Any specific requirement which is not helpful with Serialization here with the given code?

Comment: Thanks Shadov, this is exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: Hi @Ravi Jiyani.
The requirement is that I am working with legacy data, and the data is stored in that way for audit purpose. But now we need to work with that data.

Comment: @Henrique Buzachero: I don't think so then this requirement came into account for any other project/product. But yes we can start writing our own parser which can build object from mentioned String. The issue we can have is we don't have any specific package name here 'Person(name=John, age=30, telephone=Telephone(codeArea=16, number=1111-2222))' so to which class's object we are going to create? Or either we can look fields exist for such class in reflection than we will build an object of that particular type.

Answer (score 6):

Instead, do this in the class.

```
/**
 * Object as JSON string.
 * @return
 */
public String toString() {
    // Initiate GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();
    return GSON.toJson(this);
}
```

**From Object to String** : object.toString().

**From String to Object** : GSON.fromJson(jsonString, ModelClass);

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I came up with the idea of converting this string into JSON format and then convert it to the object.

So, the string generated by lombok is:

```
Person(name=John, age=30, telephone=Telephone(codeArea=16, number=1111-2222))
```

And then it is converted to JSON, by replacing the following characters **(**, **=** and **)** with **{**, **:** and **}** respectively, and removing the class names:

```
{name:John, age:30, telephone:{codeArea=16, number=1111-2222}}
```

Now it is possible to convert the JSON into an object.

I created a [project](https://github.com/Buzachero/lombok-tostring-object-converter) in Github that does this conversion.

Comment: i don't think the replacement is that simple.

Comment: @Henrique: Seems instead of using Memento, we can use Command pattern while working with Lombok and then restore the object back to its original state with such project.